# Int Array to Base64 in C# like sjcl.codec.base64.fromBits does

Tags: c#, arrays, int, base64, sjcl

In JavaScript, doing this:

```
var numbers = new Array(1042147201, -1682263442, -1463053899, 1834416100)
sjcl.codec.base64.fromBits(numbers)
```

Return "Ph3ngZu6sm6oy5G1bVb35A==", but doing this in C#:

```
var numbers = new[] { 1042147201, -1682263442, -1463053899, 1834416100 };
var byteNumbers = new byte[numbers.Length * sizeof(int)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(numbers, 0, byteNumbers, 0, byteNumbers.Length);
Convert.ToBase64String(byteNumbers);
```

Return "gecdPm6yupu1kcuo5PdWbQ=="
Why is the result different and what do I have to do to get the same result like in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at output of the 2 two pieces of code you have issue with [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of ints

```
1834416100 - > 6D 56 F7 E4
Ph3ngZu6sm6oy5G1bVb35A==  -> 3E 1D E7 81 9B BA B2 6E A8 CB 91 B5 6D 56 F7 E4
gecdPm6yupu1kcuo5PdWbQ==  -> 81 E7 1D 3E 6E B2 BA 9B B5 91 CB A8 E4 F7 56 6D
```

Possible fix: reverse each integer when adding to array as shown in [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class

```
  int value = 12345678;
  byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
  if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
     Array.Reverse(bytes);
```